# getUserMedia() not working in normal chrome but does when launching pwa-chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, getusermedia

Before someone comments that getUserMedia has to be over local or https, I know, my website is https and when I launch over localhost, I launch using a live server addon to VSCode @ port 5500.

My issue, I'm using getUserMedia() to get live updates of the user's microphone and pass that along my program to do stuff. In my 'launch.json' I have this

```
{
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "pwa-chrome",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5500",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

And this works fine. However, if I were to change 'type' to 'chrome', i.e.

```
{
    "name": "Launch Chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "chrome",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5500",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

The code no longer works and my mic isn't picked up by the program, even though the chrome page displays the "This website is using your microphone." Notification.

This means that when it comes time to put this site live onto my actual website, the microphone isn't picked up and the software doesn't work. This is the code for getting the usermedia.

```
function getMicrophoneAccess(){
    let constraints = {audio:true};
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream){
        source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        let ready = new Event('streamReady');
        dispatchEvent(ready);
    });
}
```

and then where I actually use my stream,

```
function runSoundAnalysis(){
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(soundDataArray);
    let averageSound = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < soundDataArray.length; i+=2){
        averageSound += soundDataArray[i];
    }
    averageSound /= soundDataArray.length / 2;
    if (averageSound != 0){
        console.log(averageSound); 
    }
    return averageSound;
}
```

where averageSound does = 0 in all loops of the program when running on 'chrome'.

Thanks for any help :)

Edit: To add, I checked and it works on firefox, so I must be mis-interpreting how to use chrome's getUserMedia() or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, in normal chrome, it requires that audioContext.resume() must be called before setting the state to 'live'. I simply called that in my initialisation function and it works now.